Disable double click on QFileDialog used in qt C++ application
I have qt based C++ application where we use QFileDialog to select a file.
How to disable double click on the file name listed?

Use a non native QFileDialog and try to disconnect doubleClicked signals of all its QAbstractItemViews that are children of QStackedWidget (there is a QListView and a QTreeView, but there's also a list view for bookmarks which shouldn't be disconnected)
